# Cannot create bibliography in Texmaker

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I am tearing my hair out with TexMaker.  I have a bibliography file written in Jabref.  It is called `filename.bib`.  In my tex document have a bibliography style and source command like this:

```
\bibliographystyle{aea}
\bibliography{filename}
```

The cites match the "handles" in my bib file and look like this:
`\cite{basker2013change}`

The bib file is in the directory with my tex file.  I run latex, no errors.  Bibtex, no errors.  Latex, no errors.  Latex, no errors.  DviPDF.  Look at the file and all the cites are ?.  The `bbl` file is generated but blank.  I have seen similar questions here but they all seem to be solved by following the `latex, bibtex, latex, bibtex` sequence.  But that is not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. What happens if you run `latex bibtex latex latex` from the command line, instead of using Texmaker?

Comment: What about providing us with the `.log` from both LaTeX and BibTeX runs? Can we reproduce this with a small, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Comment: Are you sure that you have no typo with `\cite{basker2013change}`, i.e. the reference key `basker2013change` is correct?

Comment: I've never seen `bibtex` say *nothing* in this sort of case. The command line is your friend. (The log is for when the command line isn't enough! Nothing wrong with using it - just more work and I'm lazy...)

Comment: Thanks. The citations had no typos. I tried using the command line instead of TeXmaker. Indeed, error messages popped up that were DIFFERENT than anything in the TeXmaker log file. I had not included the command `\bibdata{filename}`. I had clearly been confused about the role of the `\bibdata` vs `\bibliography` commands. The surprise was that TeXmaker didn't give me a hint! The command line output, instead, gave me exactly the right answer!

Comment: Sounds like you have a mis-configured Texmaker: it is probably picking up a different TeX system or is not running BibTeX at all.